# convert power point(ppt, pptx) to jpeg with php (windows)

Tags: php, com, powerpoint, jpeg

I need functionality to convert "ppt" files to images with "php" (on server). When user uploads "ppt" file server automatically converts this file into images and save to specific folder. Then I want to use this images for "jquery slider". Please help.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do with php is read those .ppt files, but it's quit hard to do so, since you need to use linux command tool call "[swish-e](http://swish-e.org/)" and it's not supporting images, since it's used for text indexing.

But i guess it's doable in flash, just like slideshare or something, hopefully there some guys from different languages reading this and can advise.